# Android Sharing files without FileProvider

Tags: android

I have tried to share a file using the [Android Sharesheet](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-system-sharesheet), and the [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) says I should use the FileProvider.

But in my situation, I can't use the FileProvider due to APK size.

Is there any way to share a file via the [Android Sharesheet](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-system-sharesheet) without using the FileProvider?

A file that I want to share is in the external storage such as "/sdcard/abc/file.zip".

---

I have already tried this, but it didn't work.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path); // FileUriExposedException
// Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + file_path); // when sharing via GMail app, a toast appears with message "Couldn't attach file"
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("application/zip");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Comment: Can you explain which influence using FileProvider has on .apk size?

Comment: I cannot explain about your question in detail because of some reasons. Please understand my situation.
But, it is true that using the FileProvider affects my apk size, and that's an important reason why I cannot use it.
So, I should find a way to share a file without the FileProvider.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? In Android 11 there is one more problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247613/1483390