# Staging app.... There was a problem parsing the package

Tags: android, apk, staging

I made an app `Ave` that updates through my website downloading a `ave.apk` package. Install from unknown sources is allowed for the app. It has been working great for years.

The update process still work perfectly in Android 4.4 and Andoid 9. But in Android 11, after downloading the new `ave.apk`, I get an error, with two popups. One below with a progress saying:

```
**Unknown**
Staging app...
____________________________
```

and a toast over it saying:

```
   There was a problem parsing the package.

                    OK.
```

Yet, I can install the `ave.apk` normally through Android Studio and also by `adb install ave.apk`. Even with the app itself, as long as I don't save the apk in the app folder!

I see this error in Android Studio console:

```
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3971/? I/[AirCmd]_MediaControlStateMonitor: isForegroundAppSupportsMediaButton : mediaSession is empty
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3971/? I/[AirCmd]_MediaControlStateMonitor: active Notification List is null
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3971/? I/[AirCmd]_PenActionRule: getAction : get default action data from remote action because pen action data is null.
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3971/? I/[AirCmd]_BleSpenButtonActionDetector: enableDoubleClickDetection: enabled=true, doubleClickWaitInterval=300
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3971/? I/[AirCmd]_RemoteSpenMainController: onSwitch : package is com.google.android.packageinstaller   and activity is com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging and isBleConnected is true and hasActions is false
2021-04-23 11:56:15.350 3917-3917/? I/AC:FloatingIconController: onBleFloatingIconStateChanged isEnabled : false, delay : 250
2021-04-23 11:56:15.351 2661-28003/? W/FuseDaemon: Invalid other package file access from com.floritfoto.apps.ave(: /storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/Downloads/ave.apk: Success
2021-04-23 11:56:15.352 11973-16410/? W/InstallStaging: Error staging apk from content URI
    java.io.IOException: read failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:519)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:320)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:1005)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:289)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:996)
        at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:184)
        at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:167)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.readBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Linux.read(Linux.java:189)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.read(ForwardingOs.java:176)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:305)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.read(ForwardingOs.java:176)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:509)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:320) 
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:1005) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:289) 
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:996) 
        at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:184) 
        at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStaging$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(InstallStaging.java:167) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2021-04-23 11:56:15.353 11973-11973/? I/Dialog: mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false, isMetaDataInActivity = false
2021-04-23 11:56:15.354 11973-11973/? I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=false
2021-04-23 11:56:15.354 11973-11973/? I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@2e1b4ce[], isFloating=true, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=false
2021-04-23 11:56:15.354 11973-11973/? D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@2e1b4ce[]
2021-04-23 11:56:15.357 11973-11973/? D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
2021-04-23 11:56:15.358 11973-11973/? D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
```

So it seems some file has vanished?? Which one? With the two popups being shown, I can still do a

```
ls /storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/Downloads/ave.apk
```

and `ave.apk` is there. So it is not the `ave.apk` that is missing. Unfortunately, Android does not tell me WHICH file is not found...

This is the URI that I get from the file provider:

```
content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/Downloads/ave.apk
```

This is the content of my xml path file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="root"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

**EDIT:** If I save the apk into the internal memory, or anywhere else in the sdcard, I can update. So this is something related to the app folder.

Comment: Have you checked the Scope Storage concept. There are restrictions for access internal folders.

Comment: My app targets API29. Anyway, the file lives inside the app folder in the external SDCard. Should this give problems?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Android 11 we cannot share files from the app own files in the external removable micro sdcard storage through `FileProvider`: the trick  `<root-path name="root" path="." />` in the provider paths .xml file does not work anymore for the own app folder. Yet, it still works for the other folders in the removable storage (besides the ones in Android/data and Android/obb). If you think this is nonsense, blame Google.

So my coward solution was to download the .apk into the public `Download` folder `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`, and install from there. Of course this works.